# how to get variable's type in template?

Tags: c++

I want to use template function to dump data into file,
here is my code:

```
template<typename T> //  T can be `std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<double> >` or `std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int> >`
void write_down(const std::string & file_path, const T & week) {
  std::fstream f;
  f.open(file_path.c_str(), std::ios::out);
  if (!f) {
    printf("openfile %s failed\n", file_path.c_str());
    return;
  }   
  for (auto w : week) {
    int date = w.first;
    auto v = w.second;
    char buffer[65536];
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d\t[", date);
    std::string b = buffer;
    for (auto i: v) {
      char buffer[65536];
      snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%.2f", i);  // here is the problem, how can i identify i is int or double!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
      b += buffer;
      b += ",";
    }   
    b += "]\n";
    f << b;
  }   
  f.close();
}
```

I have two possible input parameters type:

`std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<double> >` and `std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int> >`

the only difference is the last element, one is double one is int.

but i need to dump them into a file, which means snprintf must know the type of this variable.

how can i identify the varibale type in this template function?

Comment: Decltype may be your friend. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype

Comment: If you use C++ iostreams instead of `snprintf()` you won't need to worry about knowing the type.   `snprintf()` needs to be told what type it is outputting.   With C++ iostreams,  the compiler will work out the type, and call the appropriate overload of the `std::ostream::operator<<()`.    One of the iostream types is `std::ostrstream`, which outputs to a string stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a combination of filestream, string concatenation and `snprintf`.
You could drop the latter two and write directly to the filestream:

```cpp
for (auto w : week) {
    int date = w.first;
    auto v = w.second;

    // buffer and snprintf replaced, no need for intermediate string b:
    f << date << "\t["; 

    for (auto i : v) {
        // buffer, snprintf and string concatatenation collapsed to one line:
        f << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << i << ',';
    }   

    f << "]\n";
}
```

Here the combination of [`std::setprecision(2)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) and [`std::fixed`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) is the equivalent of the format specifier `%.2f`, it will have no effect if `i` is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on `snprintf`, something like this should work:

```
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer),
         std::is_same_v<decltype(i), int> ? "%d" : "%.2f", i);
```